# Every time I test, the number of test users is increasing...?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, docker, model-view-controller, rspec

I'm a newbie so sorry if this is a basic question.

I'm using M1 Mac.
I am creating an application by building a Rails environment with docker.

And I started Rspec from within Docker and got an error in the integration test.
and got this error.

```
Failure/Error: expect(current_path).to eq '/users/1'
     
       expected: "/users/1"
            got: "/users/56"
     
       (compared using ==)
     # ./spec/requests/users_login_spec.rb:16:in `block (3 levels) in <main>'
```

Each time I run rspec the number of users increases in multiples of 56.

```
Failure/Error: expect(current_path).to eq '/users/1'
     
       expected: "/users/1"
            got: "/users/122"
     
       (compared using ==)
     # ./spec/requests/users_login_spec.rb:16:in `block (3 levels) in <main>'
```

Here is the test code.

```
spec/requests/users_login_spec.rb

require "rails_helper"

RSpec.describe "User login", type: :request do

    before do
        @user = FactoryBot.create(:user)
    end

context "login test" do
    it "Enabled users can log in successfully"do
    visit root_path
    visit login_path
    fill_in 'session[email]', with: @user.email
    fill_in 'session[password]', with: @user.password
    click_button 'Log in'
    expect(current_path).to eq '/users/1'
    end
 end
end
```

This is the factorybot test user file.

```
spec/factories/users.rb

FactoryBot.define do
    factory :user do
      name           { 'username' }
      email          {Faker::Internet.free_email}
      password       { 'password' }
      password_confirmation       { 'password' }
      activated { true }
      activated_at { Time.zone.now }

      trait :admin do
        admin { true }
      end
  

      trait :no_activated do
        activated { false }
        activated_at { nil }
      end

    end
  end
```

Gemfile.

```
source "https://rubygems.org"
git_source(:github) { |repo| "https://github.com/#{repo}.git" }

gem "rails",                      "7.0.4"
gem "ransack"
gem "image_processing",           "1.12.2"
gem "active_storage_validations", "0.9.8"
gem "bcrypt",                     "3.1.18"
gem "faker",                      "2.21.0"
gem "will_paginate",              "3.3.1"
gem "bootstrap-will_paginate",    "1.0.0"
gem "bootstrap-sass",             "3.4.1"
gem "sassc-rails",                "2.1.2"
gem "sprockets-rails",            "3.4.2"
gem "importmap-rails",            "1.1.0"
gem "turbo-rails",                "1.1.1"
gem "stimulus-rails",             "1.0.4"
gem "jbuilder",                   "2.11.5"
gem "puma",                       "5.6.4"
gem "bootsnap",                   "1.12.0", require: false

group :development, :test do
  gem "mysql2"
  gem "debug",   "1.5.0", platforms: %i[ mri mingw x64_mingw ]
  gem "rspec-rails"
  gem 'guard-rspec', require: false
  gem "rspec_junit_formatter"
  gem 'factory_bot_rails'
end

group :development do
  gem "web-console", "4.2.0"
end

group :test do
  gem "capybara",                 "3.37.1"
  gem "selenium-webdriver",       "4.2.0"
  gem "rails-controller-testing", "1.0.5"
  gem "minitest",                 "5.15.0"
  gem "minitest-reporters",       "1.5.0"
  gem "guard",                    "2.18.0"
  gem "guard-minitest",           "2.4.6"
  gem 'rspec-rails'
  gem 'spring-commands-rspec'
  gem 'factory_bot_rails'
  gem 'database_cleaner'
  gem 'launchy'
end

group :production do
  gem "aws-sdk-s3", "1.114.0", require: false
end


gem "erb-formatter", "~> 0.4.1"

gem "dockerfile-rails", ">= 1.0", :group => :development
```

A create method in the session controller for logging in.
But this is unlikely to be wrong.
Because even if actually logged in as user 1 on the app, I were redirected to users/1.

```
app/controllers/sessions_controller.rb

class SessionsController < ApplicationController
  def new
  end

  def create
    user = User.find_by(email: params[:session][:email].downcase)
    if user && user.authenticate(params[:session][:password])
      if user.activated?
        forwarding_url = session[:forwarding_url]
        reset_session
        params[:session][:remember_me] == '1' ? remember(user) : forget(user)
        log_in user
        redirect_to forwarding_url || user
      else
        message  = "Account not activated. "
        message += "Check your email for the activation link."
        flash[:warning] = message
        redirect_to root_url
      end
    else
      flash.now[:danger] = 'Invalid email/password combination'
      render 'new', status: :unprocessable_entity
    end
  end

  def destroy
    log_out if logged_in?
    redirect_to root_url, status: :see_other
  end
end
```

I've introduced docker to an existing rails app.
This error did not occur before the introduction.
Here's the docker container configuration.(e_note is my app)
[docker config](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MdgUr.jpg)

Is there something wrong with test-db, which is a container for testing?
These are docker related files.

```
docker-compose.yml

version: "3.8"
services:
  
  db:
    image: mysql:8.0.32

    volumes:
      - dbvolume:/opt/homebrew/bin/mysql/data
  
    platform: linux/x86_64
    env_file: development.env

  test-db:
    image: mysql:8.0.32

    volumes:
      - dbvolume:/opt/homebrew/bin/mysql/data2
    environment:
      MYSQL_DATABASE: docker_test
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: password
      MYSQL_USER: test_user
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: passw0rd
    platform: linux/x86_64
  web:
  
    build:
      
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    command: bash -c "rm -f tmp/pids/server.pid && bundle exec rails s -p 3000 -b '0.0.0.0'"
    volumes:
      - .:/e_note
      - gem_data:/usr/local/bundle
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"

    depends_on:
      - db
      - test-db
    env_file: development.env

    stdin_open: true
    tty: true
    command: bundle exec rails server -b 0.0.0.0
volumes:
  dbvolume:
  gem_data:
```

```
Dockerfile

FROM ruby:3.2.0


RUN apt-get update \
    && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends \

    build-essential \
    mariadb-client \
    nodejs \
    vim \
    && apt-get clean \
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

WORKDIR /e_note


COPY Gemfile /e_note/Gemfile
COPY Gemfile.lock /e_note/Gemfile.lock

RUN gem install bundler
RUN bundle install

COPY . /e_note


COPY entrypoint.sh /usr/bin/


RUN chmod +x /usr/bin/entrypoint.sh
ENTRYPOINT ["entrypoint.sh"]

EXPOSE 3000

CMD ["rails", "server", "-b", "0.0.0.0"]
```

It's a database file.

```
database.yml

# MySQL. Versions 8.0.32 and up are supported.

default: &default
  adapter: mysql2
  encoding: utf8mb4
  pool: <%= ENV.fetch("RAILS_MAX_THREADS") { 5 } %>
  username: user # development.envで記載したユーザ名
  password: <%= ENV["MYSQL_PASSWORD"] %>
  socket: /tmp/mysql.sock
  host: db

development:
  <<: *default
  database: e_note_development

test:
  <<: *default
  username: test_user
  password: passw0rd
  database: docker_test
  host: test-db

production:
  <<: *default
  database: e_note_production
  username: <%= Rails.application.credentials.db[:user_name] %>
  password: <%= Rails.application.credentials.db[:password] %>
  host: <%= Rails.application.credentials.db[:endpoint] %>
  pool: 20
  timeout: 1000
```

This is the first time such an error.

I may have forgotten to paste some information.
It would be helpful if you could leave a comment at that time.

Thank you very much.

Comment: This is not an error. It is just the way databases auto increment primary keys. Change `expect(current_path).to eq '/users/1'` to `expect(current_path).to eq "/users/#{@user.id}"`. The multiple of 56 is probably because you have 56 tests that create a user instance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do not hardcode database id's into your specs. It's never a good idea.

```
require "rails_helper"

RSpec.describe "User login", type: :system do
  # use let/let! instead to setup test dependencies.
  let!(:user) { FactoryBot.create(:user) }
  
  # use descriptions that can be read as plain english.
  it "lets enabled users sign in" do
    visit root_path
    click_link "Sign in" # or whatever link there is in the UI
    fill_in 'Email', with: user.email # Use the labels like real person would
    fill_in 'Password', with: user.password
    click_button 'Log in'
    expect(current_path).to eq user_path(user)
  end
end
```

Rails by default handles cleaning the database between tests by using *transactional tests* - aka *transactional fixtures*. The test is wrapped in a database transaction which is rolled back in the teardown phase. This is a very fast strategy but one consequence of this is that the autoincrementing counters for the tables won't be reset like if the table was dropped or truncated between tests.

Comment: Thank you. I will make a conscious effort to write legible English.

Comment: One more thing that I didn't notice until now - you're using `type: :request` but what you're writing here is actually a system/feature spec. The difference is that request specs are used for lower level testing where you just send HTTP requests with the test methods for it and test the response and system specs use Capybara to test the user story and navigate around the app by clicking links and filling in forms.

Comment: https://github.com/rspec/rspec-rails#system-specs-feature-specs-request-specswhats-the-difference

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I should have checked the usage of each system spec and request spec. After changing to the docker environment, the number of parts to check has increased, but I will do my best.